# LSP autocomplete not ful complete [mfussenegger/nvim-jdtls]

Tags: neovim, nvim-lspconfig

I use `hrsh7th/nvim-compe` for autocomplete and `mfussenegger/nvim-jdtls` for Java neovim development (If it's important) and I would like to get advice about unexpected problem:

When I type for example `System.out.pr...`, plugin show me that I can complete it to `System.out.println`. But when I choose one of variants, round open-close brackets don't complete, so I get `System.out.println` as result.
Although if I install `windwp/nvim-autopairs` additionally and make open brackets it was completed by close brackets

I didn't make major changes in config which I get from official github, so I have no idea what I do incorrectly

```
require'compe'.setup {
  enabled = true;
  autocomplete = true;
  debug = false;
  min_length = 1;
  preselect = 'enable';
  throttle_time = 80;
  source_timeout = 200;
  resolve_timeout = 800;
  incomplete_delay = 400;
  max_abbr_width = 100;
  max_kind_width = 100;
  max_menu_width = 100;

source = {
    path = true;
    buffer = true;
    calc = true;
    nvim_lsp = true;
    nvim_lua = true;
    vsnip = true;
    ultisnips = true;
    luasnip = true;
  };
```

thanks

Comment: `hrsh7th/nvim-compe` is depreciated, you want to move to `hrsh7th/nvim-cmp`, I believe that is a possible cause of your issue.

Also btw what do you mean by "But when I choose one of variants"? As in choosing any autocomplete it provides or a it only applies to specific ones

Comment: Thank you, I'll double check your advice
About variants I meant to say that if I choose anyithing which is not required brackets, for example a variable, that it works correctly, otherwise when I select specific ones which should be completed with brackets, for example a constructor/method, then plugin doesn't complete open-close brackets after this and complete only the name of target selection

sorry for my worst explanation, english is not my mother language